# Jetpack Compose First Try - Correct Usage and what can I do better?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I build a really small practicing application, but I found some Questions.

```
package com.example.jetrecept

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.sharp.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.sharp.Delete
import androidx.compose.material.icons.sharp.Edit
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Dialog
import com.example.jetrecept.ui.theme.JetReceptTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetReceptTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    MainContent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    var recipeTitle by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val ingredientList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Ingredient>() }

    var amount by remember { mutableStateOf("") } // Change to Double
    var unit by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var notation by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    RecipeContent(
        recipeTitle = recipeTitle,
        onRecipeTitleChange = { recipeTitle = it },
        ingredientList = ingredientList,
        onIngredientListUpdate = { ingredient: Ingredient, i: Int -> ingredientList[i] = ingredient},
        onIngredientListAdd = { ingredientList.add(it) },
        onIngredientListRemoveItem = { ingredientList.removeAt(it)},

        amount = amount,
        onAmountChange = { amount = it},
        unit = unit,
        onUnitChange = { unit = it},
        notation = notation,
        onNotationChange = { notation = it}
        )
    RecipeHeader(
        recipeTitle = recipeTitle
    )
}


@Composable
fun RecipeHeader(
    recipeTitle: String
) {
    //JetReciptTheme {
    Column {
        //Text(text="recipetitle: $recipeTitle") // Just for testing, if hoisting works
    }
    //}
}

@Composable
fun RecipeContent(
    recipeTitle: String,
    onRecipeTitleChange: (String) -> Unit,
    ingredientList: MutableList<Ingredient>,
    onIngredientListAdd: (Ingredient) -> Unit,
    onIngredientListUpdate: (Ingredient, Int) -> Unit,
    onIngredientListRemoveItem: (Int) -> Unit,

    amount: String, // change to Double,
    onAmountChange: (String) -> Unit, //change to (Double) -> Unit,
    unit: String,
    onUnitChange: (String) -> Unit,
    notation: String,
    onNotationChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(21.dp)) {
        // Headline
        Text(text="Add new recipe",
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(34.dp),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center)

        // Title of recipe - input
        SectionHeadline(title = "Recipename")
        TextField(
            value = recipeTitle,
            onValueChange = { onRecipeTitleChange(it) },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(bottom = 34.dp),
            // Keyboard Action fehlt noch 
            )

        // Ingredient - section
        SectionHeadline(title = "Ingredients")

        // Writing headline over the Ingredient table
        if (ingredientList.isNotEmpty()) {
            IngredientDescription(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom=4.dp),
                firstColumn = "Nr.",
                secondColumn = "Amount",
                thirdColumn = "Unit",
                fourthColumn = "Notation"
                )
            Divider(modifier = Modifier
                .height(10.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 4.dp, top = 4.dp))
        }

        // Print all Ingredients to an Row
        ingredientList.mapIndexed { index, ingredient -> IngredientRow(
            id = index,
            ingredient = ingredient,
            onIngredientListUpdate = onIngredientListUpdate,
            onIngredientListRemoveItem = onIngredientListRemoveItem,

            amount = amount,
            onAmountChange = onAmountChange,
            unit = unit,
            onUnitChange = onUnitChange,
            notation = notation,
            onNotationChange = onNotationChange
        )
        }

        // Ingredient input row
        Row {
            TextField(
                value = amount,
                onValueChange = { onAmountChange(it)},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(100.dp)
                    .padding(end = 8.dp),
                label = { Text(text="amount") },
                singleLine = true
                )
            TextField(
                value = unit,
                onValueChange = { onUnitChange(it)},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(80.dp)
                    .padding(end = 8.dp),
                label = { Text(text = "unit") },
                singleLine = true
                )
            TextField(
                value = notation,
                onValueChange = { onNotationChange(it)},
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1F),
                label = { Text(text = "notation")},
                singleLine = true
                )
        }

        Spacer(modifier= Modifier.height(8.dp))

        // Add - Button, adding Ingredients
        IconButton(
            buttonText = "add",
            icon = Icons.Sharp.Add,
            iconDescription = "add icon",
            enabled = amount.isNotBlank() && unit.isNotBlank() && notation.isNotBlank(),
            onClick = {
                onIngredientListAdd(Ingredient(amount=amount, unit=unit, notation=notation))
                onAmountChange(""); onUnitChange(""); onNotationChange("")
            })
    }
}

@Composable
fun IngredientRow(
    id: Int = 1,
    ingredient: Ingredient,
    onIngredientListUpdate: (Ingredient, Int) -> Unit,
    onIngredientListRemoveItem: (Int) -> Unit,

    amount: String,
    onAmountChange: (String) -> Unit,
    unit: String,
    onUnitChange: (String) -> Unit,
    notation: String,
    onNotationChange: (String) -> Unit
    ) {
    var buttonVisibility by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    var showEditDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

    Column( modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        IngredientDescription(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { buttonVisibility = !buttonVisibility },
            firstColumn = "$id",
            secondColumn = ingredient.amount,
            thirdColumn = ingredient.unit,
            fourthColumn = ingredient.notation
        )

        if (buttonVisibility) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 8.dp, top = 8.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
                ) {
                IconButton(
                    buttonText = "edit",
                    icon = Icons.Sharp.Edit,
                    iconDescription = "edit icon",
                    onClick = {
                        onAmountChange( ingredient.amount)
                        onUnitChange( ingredient.unit)
                        onNotationChange( ingredient.notation)
                        showEditDialog = true}
                )
                IconButton(
                    buttonText = "delete",
                    icon = Icons.Sharp.Delete,
                    iconDescription = "delete icon",
                    onClick = { onIngredientListRemoveItem(id) }
                )
            }
        }
        Divider(modifier = Modifier
            .height(10.dp)
            .padding(bottom = 4.dp, top = 4.dp))

        if (showEditDialog) {
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    onAmountChange(""); onUnitChange(""); onNotationChange("")
                    showEditDialog = false},
                title = {Text(text="Edit ingredient")},
                text = {
                    Column {
                        Text(text="Amount:")
                        TextField(value = amount, onValueChange = { onAmountChange(it) })
                        Text(text="Unit:")
                        TextField(value = unit, onValueChange = { onUnitChange(it) })
                        Text(text="Notation:")
                        TextField(value = notation, onValueChange = { onNotationChange(it) })
                    }
                },
                confirmButton = { onIngredientListUpdate(
                Ingredient(amount= amount, unit= unit, notation= notation), id)
                    Button(onClick = {
                        showEditDialog = false
                        buttonVisibility = false
                        onAmountChange(""); onUnitChange(""); onNotationChange("")}) {
                        Text(text = "apply")
                    }
                                },
                dismissButton = {
                    Button(onClick = {
                        showEditDialog = false
                        buttonVisibility = false
                        onAmountChange(""); onUnitChange(""); onNotationChange("")}) {
                        Text(text = "discard")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SectionHeadline(title: String) {
    Text(text = title)
    Divider(modifier = Modifier.height(2.dp))
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
}

@Composable
fun IngredientDescription(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    firstColumn: String, secondColumn: String, thirdColumn: String, fourthColumn:String) {
    Row( modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(bottom = 4.dp, top = 4.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(text = firstColumn, modifier = Modifier.width(30.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Text(text = secondColumn, modifier = Modifier.width(60.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Text(text = thirdColumn, modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp), textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        Text(text = fourthColumn, modifier = Modifier.weight(1F))
    }
}

@Composable
fun IconButton(
    buttonText: String,
    icon: ImageVector,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    iconDescription: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Button(onClick = onClick, enabled = enabled) {
        Text(text=buttonText, modifier = Modifier.padding(end=5.dp))
        Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = iconDescription)
    }
}

// data class Ingredient (var amount: Double, var unit: String, var notation: String)
data class Ingredient (var amount: String, var unit: String, var notation: String)
```

Is the way of hoisting correct? I mean, I take most of the states out of the Composables but some states inside are just for internal working. Should I also take this out of the Composable to make it complete stateless (`buttonVisibility` and `showEditDialog`)?

Are there any things I can do better?

Comment: It all depends on your needs. If you don't need to access some value outside of one composable, there is only one reason to make the view "complete stateless" - if you wanna create a test for this view and test behaviour of these specific parameters. Otherwise it's totally fine to left `buttonVisibility` and `showEditDialog` where they are now.

Answer (score 0):

First things is need **Separation of Concerns** to your code. So, that in future if needed to modification you can easily modify it without figuring out how each compose function is design, how state managed and which file LocalDb connected.
Take an example of Note taking app.

MainActivity.kt --->

```
package com.example.note    
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private val notesState:NotesState by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NotesTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Main(notesState=notesState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Main(notesState:NotesState) {

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    )
    {
        ShowColumnContent(notesState=notesState)
    }
}
@Composable
fun ShowColumnContent(notesState:NotesState){
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    )
    {
        Notes(notesState = notesState)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        UserInputField(notesState = notesState)
    }
}
@Composable
fun Notes(notesState:NotesState){
    val allNotes=notesState.providerArray.collectAsState().value
    LazyColumn(content = {
   items(allNotes.size){
   index -> Text(text=allNotes[index].text)
   }
    }
        )
}
@Composable
fun UserInputField(notesState:NotesState){
    val singleNote=notesState.userInput.collectAsState().value
    TextField(value = singleNote,
        onValueChange = {it -> notesState.updateTextField(it) },
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = {
                notesState.updateProviderArray(singleNote)
            }
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        )
            )
}
```

viewmodel.kt--->

```
package com.example.note.viewmodel
class NotesState: ViewModel (){
    //it's for array of notes
    private val _providerArray=MutableStateFlow(NoteProviderArray)
    val providerArray:StateFlow<Array<NoteProvider>>
        get()=_providerArray.asStateFlow()

    fun updateProviderArray(singleText:String){
        _providerArray.update {
                noteProviderArray -> noteProviderArray.plus(NoteProvider(text= singleText))
        }
    }

    // it's for changing the text Field at run time

    private val _userInput=MutableStateFlow("")
    val userInput:StateFlow<String>
       get()=_userInput.asStateFlow()

    fun updateTextField(text:String){
        _userInput.value=text
    }
}
```

data.kt---->

```
package com.example.notes.data

data class NoteProvider(val text:String = "")

val NoteProviderArray:Array<NoteProvider> = arrayOf(NoteProvider())
```

---

```
1.Data class is responsible for giving data to viewmodel class. This Data class is sometimes connected with local DB and also have different type of Data class for store different data.
2.viewmodel class taken data from data class and give data to whole app or any UI class needed. It's the state house of whole app. 
3.MainActivity or UI file(s) that's show UI to mobile via taken data from viewmodel class.
```

So, data flow in UNI-DIRECTIONAL.
Starting of an app data going to 1->2->3 flow and when data get from user then data going to 3->2->1 order for update state and data storage.

```
This is MVVM architecture.
1. Data storage/data warehouse
2.viewmodel/state warehouse
3.All UI elements
Cleaner code make it easy for small app also.
```

Comment: Can you write it a bit better? The text is alltogether. And also can you make an example with code?